# Sams Teach Yourself WPF in 24 Hours: Inconsistent Results with OnChanged Event

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have just started working with WPF, and have been reading "*Sams Teach Yourself WPF*".  In chapter 6, it introduces binding to properties in the code behind as shown below.  This method has inconsistent success for me.

In my current project, this method worked for two doubles whose values I bound to Labels.  When I tried to use the same method to bind a bool to a MenuItem's IsEnabled property, the method fails.

I then went back to the simple example from the book, and changed the property type from String to bool.  In that case, I was able to bind a bool to a Button and TextBox.

I have noticed when this method fails, the EventHandler is always null in the OnChanged function.  What am I missing?

```
private String _myString;
public String MyString
{
     get { return _myString; }
     set 
     {   
          _myString = value;
          OnMyStringChanged();
     }
}

public event EventHandler MyStringChanged;

private void OnMyStringChanged()
{
     if (MyStringChanged != null)
          MyStringChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I have the following XAML in my MainWindow class.  In the constructor of MainWindow, I set DataContext to a new instance of the class containing MyString.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyString, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Margin="4"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1"
        Height="40"
        Margin="4"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="{Binding Path=MyString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: We need to see your xaml as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that the code that instantiates a copy of your form needs to register a listener to the "MyStringChanged" event.

Check where you declare the instance of your form:
i.e.

```
var myForm = new TestForm();
TestForm.Show();
```

You'd need to add:

```
var myForm = new TestForm();
myForm.MyStringChanged += someHandlingMethod;
TestForm.Show();
```

Something like that should be mentioned in the sample.

Honestly though it isn't a great sample from what I've read. They're making a WinForm style app using WPF. To learn WPF you need to be looking at MVVM. That is certainly not a 24 hour task. Doing the above you may as well be building a WinForm application, it will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with me.  I had misspelled the variable name in the XAML binding path.  I was expecting to receive a compiler warning or exception, if the binding path was invalid.  Even changing the binding mode to "TwoWay" does not produce any warnings or run-time exceptions with a non-existent binding path.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: That is one of the more annoying "features" of WPF bindings. Check the output window at runtime whenever you get unexpected missing behaviour. After a few "grrr!!!" moments with binding it becomes second nature. :)